# duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:

Tags: objective-c

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:
>   XYZMobileApp/Build/Intermediates/XYZMobileApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZMobileApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability.o
>
> XYZMobileApp/BusinessLogic/Library/XtifyLib/XtifyPush.embeddedframework/XtifyPush.framework/XtifyPush(Reachability.o)

I am getting this error:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:

and

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Do you add any settings in Other Linker Flags of the target ?

Comment: No I didn't add any settings in Other Linker Flags. I renamed Reachability file using refactor. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you have used Reachablity class two times in your code.
One is included in the framework XtifyPush.framework and other you have included in the bundle.
Remove the one you are adding to remove the duplicacy.

Comment: I agree but I think he still needs to use Reachability in it's project. If XTify's Reachability is private then try renaming it to i.e. MyReachability.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you did not include the Reachability.m -> implementation file instead of Reachability.h-> header file.

And also make sure you didn't  include Reachability in you your unit test target this can also cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed Reachability class as well as filename in library to "MyReachability". Xcode asked me to unlock the file as it was under pod. I unlocked it and after building i got few errors in my framework that Reachability class not found. I renamed the class references there as well to MyReachability and it worked fine. Hope this helps.